# Pulseaudio not using card I want output from

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

Sound on Ubuntu stopped working (however on Windows 7 it works).
I just tried *ubuntu-bug audio* and gave the following output:

> You don't seem to have configured PulseAudio to use the card you want
>   output from (Internal Audio - HDA Intel PCH).
>   You can fix that using pavucontrol or the GNOME volume control.

And the output below is when pulseaudio is written on command line

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance. I have run `alsamixer` and the card is not muted.

Comment: have you tried running "alsamixer" in console, check if sound is muted in alsamixer

Comment: no, it is not muted

Answer (score 0):

From that error message, I'm guessing you need to go to the Volume Menu -> "System Settings..." -> "Output" tab, then select the right hardware device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are two hardwares: Internal Audio Analog Stereo and High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI). I have also tested the speakers. Neither works.

Comment: You probably want "Internal Audio Analog Stereo". BTW: Here are some audio debugging hints: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio